# Measure/track list performance

Tags: 2013, custom-list, performance

I would like to track or measure custom list performance in SharePoint 2013 on Premises.
What I would like to be measured is time of custom views loading, workflow loading and similar stuff.

I found out today about Developer designer, but I am not sure if I would get info out of it what I need.

Any suggestion what application could I use?